# Backup a single table in SQL server not using Select into

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

For SQL Server 2008 is there an out of the box way to backup a singe table? On other database I've seen straightforward backup and restore commands for a single table but have not found it on SQL Server.

I am looking for commands like backup table and restore table which I've come across for other databases.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296107/sql-server-partial-database-backup-excluding-some-tables

Answer (score 0):

Use powershell to copy the table from one server/database to another.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/06/use-powershell-to-copy-a-table-between-two-sql-server-instances.aspx

This uses the sql client library and bulk copy.  As long as you have credentials, this can be executed anywhere as long as powershell is installed!

Answer (score 0):

There is one option using SSMS.

Check [this](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/greg_low/archive/2010/06/07/backup-a-single-table-in-sql-server-using-ssms.aspx) out.